# How to compare an array of object generate automatically to avoid double in it?

Tags: javascript, image, object, p5.js

I'm making an art project. In it I display images when a key is pressed. Like if you press "a" it display an image of a abstract "a". The problem is that I want to manipulate those image once they are displayed, so I've tried to stock them into an `array` but due to the function `draw()` of p5.js it's become bigger and bigger.

I'v tried to compare object while they are created but it doesn't work  So I'm looking for a way to compare if the object exist or not.

My code is like:

```
draw() {
  if (letterToDisp != 0 && ){
    new Objet(temp, letterToDisp);//temp is a number random {0,1}
  }
}

function Objet(rand, lettre) {
  if (CheckIfExistObject(rand, lettre)) {
    img[nbLetter++] = new Img(rand, lettre);
  }
  else {
    new Img(rand, lettre);
  }
}

function CheckIfExistObject(alea, lettre) {
  var objectsAreSame = true;
  img.forEach(function (test) {
    if (test == new Img(alea, lettre)) {
      objectsAreSame = false;
      return objectsAreSame;
    }
  });

  return objectsAreSame;
}
```

So this generate me an infinite array of `object` so i don't notice how compare them and see how to compare them. Where I need help is how to build my `CheckIfExistObject` function.

Comment: I'm not sureI fully understand your goal: do you want to "save" images of a certain letter (so each "A" will point to the same "A"-image)? Or if not what logic do you exactly want to have; which part is not working?

Comment: It's strange and hard top explain, but actually my program just print a specific image for a keypressed. And I can't manipulate those image because they are not stocked into variable. And it's what I'm trying to do. If you pressed a key the image is stock only one time in a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Javascript**

```
const pressedKeys = {};

function createImage(character) {
  const image = character;

  // ... you should actually build your image here  
  pressedKeys[character] = image;

  return image;
}

document.addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {
  const character = event.key.toLowerCase();
  const alreadyPressed = pressedKeys[character];

  return alreadyPressed || createImage(character);
});
```

I think this is what you're looking for. In the `pressedKeys` object you keep track of keys already pressed. On each keypress you check if the current key is already pressed, if so return whatever you want to store. If it's not yet pressed, create a new image, store it and return it in order to be used.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you I'll adapt this to my project ! :-)